WPF windows with ResizeMode="NoResize" and WindowStyle="None" won't drop shadow
I'm having problems with a window in WPF
if I set :
ResizeMode="NoResize" 
WindowStyle="None"

the window will look flat and without rounded borders and shadow beneath.
Is the a way to solve this? without using a border with effect DropShadow
I've tried this solution: dropshadow-for-wpf-borderless-window , but the window will refuse to render the content and just display a white rectangle with the appropriate shadow and rounded borders.


Thanks in advance
dropshadow-for-wpf-borderless-window

You could use the DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea, GetWindowLong and GetWindowLong Win32 APIs to get a window without a non-resizable window without a title bar but with a drop shadow and border:
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    [DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
    private static extern int DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(IntPtr hWnd, ref Margins pMarInset);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct Margins
    {
        public int cxLeftWidth;
        public int cxRightWidth;
        public int cyTopHeight;
        public int cyBottomHeight;
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Title = string.Empty;
        //ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
    }

    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

        IntPtr hWnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
        Margins margins = new Margins { cxLeftWidth = -1, cxRightWidth = -1, cyTopHeight = -1, cyBottomHeight = -1 };
        DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hWnd, ref margins);
        const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
        const int WS_SYSMENU = 0x80000;
        SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE,
            GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_SYSMENU);

    }
}


